# No Backdrop Button in node editor

Tags: interface, node-editor

I'm having issues with the Node Editor. I have clicked render image button but I am unsure as to whether it has worked. No image actually comes up, and there is no backdrop button.
[image: blender showing the node editor]

Answer (score 3):

You have *Shader* or material nodes selected, what you want are *Compositing* nodes which is the button directly to the right of that.

If you want to see the output of your render in the compositor, you need a *Viewer* node connected to the render layer you are working with. So switch to compositing nodes, add a viewer node, tick backdrop and you should see your render.

Comment: but it should show up in any area when the render ends

Comment: @Chebhou Backdrop is only shown when you are using compositing nodes as it shows what the ___Viewer___ node is connected to.

Comment: i think he is about the final render result that should come up when you render

Comment: @Chebhou There is no _backdrop_ button in the final render result which is the image editor. Only in the node editor.

Comment: ok, i thought that the problem is with Image_editor not showing up when he render "because it is supposed to override the UI and display the result"

Comment: @Chebhou Oh, I have my display set to keep ui that's why but the image editor can also access the output of the viewer node.